# apply() a function on dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

In my function below, `myfun` checks first if a certain condition is met, and then continues the operation.

This checking happens inside the function.

Is there a way to check before the function is applied?

For example, `if [column] == xyx, .apply(myfun)`

Some code below:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['hi','hello','hi','hello'],
                 'col2':['random', 'words', 'in', 'here']})
print(x)

    col1    col2
0     hi  random
1  hello   words
2     hi      in
3  hello    here
```

My function checks if `row['col1'] == 'hi'` and returns the string `success` else `np.nan`.

```
def myfun(row):

    # if this row contains string 'hi'
    if row['col1'] == 'hi':

        return 'success'

    # otherwise return nan
    else:

        return pd.np.nan

# applying the function
x['result'] = x.apply(myfun,axis=1)


# result

    col1    col2   result
0     hi  random  success
1  hello   words      NaN
2     hi      in  success
3  hello    here      NaN
```

Is it possible to apply the function to only those rows where `col1` == `'hi'`, rather than doing it inside the `apply()` func?

Note: I would prefer a solution using `apply()`. I know there are other options like `np.where`.

Comment: "Note: I would prefer a solution using apply(). I know there are other options like np.where." Can you explain precisely why? `apply` is a slow Python row-wise loop, while `np.where` will be at least partially vectorised.

Comment: Because there are a lot more operations happening in my `apply` function than in this toy example.

Comment: more specifically there is an api call in my apply function, and I think the  server would explode if i used a vectorized method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use `apply()` based on a condition. I can now remove the condition checking from the function:

```
def myfun(row):

    return 'success'

# applying the function based on condition
x['result'] = x[x['col1']=='hi'].apply(myfun,axis=1)
```

I can also create a mask first.

```
mask = (x['col1']=='hi')

# applying the function based on condition
x['result'] = x[mask].apply(myfun,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and you better like this than `apply`.

Because `apply` loop on every row and `loc` is a vectorized method. Even if apply can be really powerful, I try to avoid it when I can

```py
x.loc[x['col1']=='hi', 'result'] = 'success'
```

Comment: there is an api call in my `apply` function, so I need it to be slow.